# Horizontal smooth scroll animation in recyclerview with fixed width android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I am new in android with kotlin.

I have recylerview with unlimit amount of items. But i want to show only 6 items per view. I used constraint layout in items to bind data. I used **setOnTouchListener** and used drag functionality. If my drag intensity is short and direction is on left side so i passed the 2 and if its in right direction i passed -2. If my drag intensity is long and direction is on left side so i passed 6 and if in right direction i passed -6 in **smoothScrollBy** function by pixel. I am using **smoothScrollBy**, the items are scrolling fine but if i could drag quickly the first and last items are cut in the edge side. Then i am using normal **scrollby** its working fine. Can you please suggest me some solution as to why this is happening?

**Adapter file**

```
 override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.calender_item_layout, parent, false)

        itemView.layoutParams.width = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.widthPixels / 6

        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }
```

**CustomeRecyclerView**

```
class CustomRecyclerView(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) :
    RecyclerView(context, attrs) {


init{
     layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context).apply {
            orientation = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
            stackFromEnd = true
      }

     
        setOnTouchListener(object : OnSwipeTouchListener() {
          // pass 2 or 6 based on drag intensity
          // 2 or -2 for short drag 6 and -6 for long drag 
          post { scrollItem(value) }
        }
   }

    fun scrollItem(value: Int) {
       smoothScrollBy(inpixel(value), 0)
    }

    private fun inpixel(offset: Int): Int {
         val dim = Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics
         return (dim.widthPixels / 6) * offset
    }
}
```

thanks